# Tabs not loading pane information

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I’m having a problem with Tabs in semantic-ui-react, I’m trying to use a vertical tab like shown here

https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/tab#tab-example-vertical-true

The code used in the example is this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Tab } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const panes = [
  { menuItem: 'Tab 1', render: () => <Tab.Pane>Tab 1 Content</Tab.Pane> },
  { menuItem: 'Tab 2', render: () => <Tab.Pane>Tab 2 Content</Tab.Pane> },
  { menuItem: 'Tab 3', render: () => <Tab.Pane>Tab 3 Content</Tab.Pane> },
]

const TabExampleVerticalTrue = () => (
  <Tab menu={{ fluid: true, vertical: true, tabular: 'right' }} panes={panes} />
)

export default TabExampleVerticalTrue
```

Using this code as shown above works as it should, i.e when I click on a tab it loads the information for the tab in the tab pane.

In my render function I have

```
<Tab menu={{ fluid: true, vertical: true, tabular: 'right' }} panes={panes} />
```

When I try to replace the panes provided with my code below it doesn’t change the tab when clicked, it shows the new tab is clicked but doesn't load the new tab pane.

```
const panes = [];
for(var i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++) {
  panes.push({ menuItem: (i+1).toString(), key:{i}, render: () =>(<Tab.Pane>{i}</Tab.Pane>) })
};
```

Thanks

EDIT: I think it is changing the tab but when rendering I think the i value in the tab pane is rendering the value at the end of the for loop and not setting the value as what i is inside the for loop for each iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a loop that creates closures (the `render` functions), which refer to the var-declared loop variable `i`. After the loop, all render functions refer to the same `i`, which will now have value `2`. You can fix it by changing `var` to `let`, which causes the `i` in each loop iteration to have its own scope. Alternatively, you can use a `map` instead of a loop:

```
const panes = new Array(2).fill().map((__, i) => (
  { menuItem: ''+(i+1), key:{i}, render: () => <Tab.Pane>{i+1}</Tab.Pane> }
));
```

Comment: It's working now thanks, my original problem was having a `<Form.TextArea/>` inside the Tab so that when it changes you can constantly go back and forth between each tab and continue writing. Do you know if there's a way to do this simply without having to store the data typed into state?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking (you might want to make this a new question) but in most cases you'll want to maintain user input in the state.

Comment: If you changed the `{i+1}` in `<Tab.Pane>` with `<Form.TextArea>`, when you change to and from tabs the state of the text area is lost. I think the simplest idea would be to store the value in the local state with an onChange function but running into problems with adding into json array by index

Comment: What you want is probably not that hard, but I would really suggest to create a new question for it. The comments are not an ideal place to do this, and with a new question, also others will chime in.

Comment: @W22 When you switch between tabs the tab content (pane) gets destroyed by default. Use the attribute `renderActiveOnly={false}` - it's in the documentation: https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/tab/